# PTY allocation request failed on channel 0 when SSH

Tags: ssh, centos

I have tried this:

```
rm -rf /dev/ptmx 
mknod /dev/ptmx c 5 2 
chmod 666 /dev/ptmx 
umount /dev/pts 
rm -rf /dev/pts 
mkdir /dev/pts 
mount /dev/pts
```

But I came across:

> umount: /dev/pts: device is busy.
>       (In some cases useful info about processes that use
>        the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))

The Parameter `-v` showed me this debug output:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to xx.xxx.xx.xxx ([xx.xxx.xx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
```

I have no idea now...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using CentOS 6 32Bit, here is the probable solution:

1. Login to our web panel
2. Click "NoVNC Console" and login as root
3. Then edit /etc/rc.sysinit and look for this line: /sbin/start_udev
   Remove that line and restart the container and you might be good to go!

END